# Variável para validar campo 'Login'?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou com dificuldades em criar uma variável para validar o meu campo Login.

Por exemplo, nos meus campos 'Nome' e 'Sobrenome', eu tenho esta variável:

```
var padrao = /[^a-zà-ú]/gi;
```

Que valido de tal forma: se 'Nome' ou 'Sobrenome' não estiver conforme tal variável, ou seja, não pode conter números nem caracteres especiais, somente estes da variável, ele dá uma mensagem de erro.

Quero fazer o mesmo com meu campo 'Login' (nome de usuário), quero que seja uma variável que não possa entrar acentos nem caracteres especiais, apenas números e letras, maiúsculas ou minúsculas.

Poderiam me ajudar na criação de tal variável?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você usa `^` dentro de colchetes (`[]`), você está dizendo que **não** quer os caracteres que estão nos colchetes - esta expressão também é chamada de [*Negated Character Class*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

Mas se você quer uma expressão que aceite apenas letras (minúsculas e maiúsculas) e números, você deve retirar o `^` dos colchetes e colocar os caracteres que precisa dentro deles.

Além disso, seria interessante colocar um `^` no início (fora dos colchetes, no início, [significa "começo da string"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)), e um `$` no final (que significa "fim da string").

Também coloquei um [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". A expressão final fica assim:

```js
var padrao = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

console.log(padrao.test('abcABC01')); // true
console.log(padrao.test('ábc')); // tem caractere acentuado, retorna false
```

- `^` é o "início da string""
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` é "uma ou mais ocorrências de letras minúsculas (`a-z`), maiúsculas (`A-Z`) ou números (`0-9`)"
- `$` é o "fim da string"

Ou seja, ela verifica se todos os caracteres da string são letras ou números.

Answer (score 1):

- O  circunflexo `^` marca o começo de uma linha
- o cifrão `$` marca o fim de uma linha
- `i` tanto faz, maiúsculas ou minúsculas
- `[a-z]` letras no intervalo de `a` até `z`, quando temos um traço `-` entre dois caracteres, isso representa todo o intervalo entre eles
- `[]` conjunto, qualquer caractere incluído no conjunto, inclusive espaço

```js
var validacao = /^[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+$/i
var nomes = ["Fulano", "Fulano com espaços", "Céçlañô", "ze234", "FulanoSemEspaçosComcecedilha", "FulanoSemEspacosSemcecedilha"]
nomes.forEach(function(nome) {
    console.log(nome + ": " + validacao.test(nome))
});
```

> dentro do conjunto você pode definir as letras permitidas :)

### Finalmente

**para seu caso, apenas números e letras, maiúsculas ou minúsculas**

```js
var validacao = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i
var nomes = ["Fulano", "Fulano com espaços", "Céçlañô", "ze234", "FulanoSemEspaçosComcecedilha", "FulanoSemEspacosSemcecedilha"]
nomes.forEach(function(nome) {
    console.log(nome + ": " + validacao.test(nome))
});
```

> como dito antes, o modificador `i` é usado para realizar correspondência insensível a maiúsculas e minúsculas.

**Outra forma:**

```js
var validacao = /^[a-z\d]+$/i
var nomes = ["Fulano", "Fulano com espaços", "Céçlañô", "ze234", "FulanoSemEspaçosComcecedilha", "FulanoSemEspacosSemcecedilha"]
nomes.forEach(function(nome) {
    console.log(nome + ": " + validacao.test(nome))
});
```

> `\d` o mesmo que `[0-9]`

**Podemos reduzir ainda mais a expressão**

```js
var validacao = /^[\w]+$/
var nomes = ["Fulano", "Fulano com espaços", "Céçlañô", "ze234", "FulanoSemEspaçosComcecedilha", "FulanoSemEspacosSemcecedilha", "tudominusculas", "TUDOMAIUSCULAS"]
nomes.forEach(function(nome) {
    console.log(nome + ": " + validacao.test(nome))
});
```

> `\w` - alfanuerico